# How to generate a Visual Basic .NET client from an OpenAPI definition?

Tags: vb.net, swagger, .net-3.5, code-generation, openapi

I need to call a REST API from a Visual Basic .NET project (.NET Framework 3.5). They gave me an OpenAPI .yaml file. In the Swagger Editor I can't generate the client for Visual Basic, only for C#. I tried to export the JSON from the Swagger Editor and paste it as a class in Visual Studio, but the generated class seems to be incorrect and incomplete.

Is there a way to generate a Visual Basic .NET client from an OpenAPI definition?

Comment: Generate the c# client, then convert to vb using any of the many online code converter tools.  If this is a new project might actually be worth your effort to try c# as most examples and documentation in that space will be C#.  Might also be worth posting both your json and classes you created with an explication of what’s not right.

Comment: You might see if you can generate the JSON by using  [JSON to YAML](https://www.json2yaml.com/). Then use [JSON Utils](https://jsonutils.com/) to convert the JSON to VB.NET classes.